# C# Windows Forms Application - Beginner and unsure how to proceed next

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C# and am trying to self educate myself in order to use it at work.

I am trying to write a program for financial planning. My goal is to have it accept the amount the user is planning to save (financial goal), yearly investment, and an interest rate. Each time “Next year” button is pressed the program would calculate the balance at the end of the year, which includes previous balance plus the yearly investment incremented by the entered interest rate. It would also show by how much the current balance is short of the entered financial goal. Preferably, I would like to use currency format to show the balance and the remaining amount.

I have provided a visual example below of how I evision it, however the numbers were manually entered as I am having difficulty making the code to work.

[image]

The following is the current state of my code that works great:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Assignment_1___1._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        int year = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            year ++;
            double goal = 0;

            if (double.TryParse(txtGoal.Text, out goal))
            {
                txtYear.Text = year.ToString();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value!");
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am at a loss of how to proceed next, despite my best efforts to search online. I assume this is due to my current lack of knowledge related to C# programming. All that is remaining is to make the 'Balance' and 'Remaining' text boxes fill out as envisioned.

Comment: just wanted to check and see if you were able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simply storing the value as a decimal and displaying/parsing it as a currency

[ToString for currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var displayValue = currencyDec.ToString('c');
```

[Parse Currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (!Decimal.TryParse(inputValue, out currencyDec))
        throw new ArgumentException('inputValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use + which is a concatenation operator

```
txtBalance.Text="$"+ dblBalance.toString();
```

Here txtBalance is a textbox and dblBalalnce is the balance amount.

Comment: This is bad code.  It doesn't allow for internationalization. Decimal places etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

You want

```
textBox.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "{0:C2}", value);
```

OR...

```
textBox.Text = value.ToString("C2", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Int32 _CurrentYear = 0;
    private Double _CurrentBalance = 0;
    private Double _CurrentRemaining = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxGoal.Text = "100000";
        textBoxYearlyInvest.Text = "2000";
        textBoxInterestRate.Text = "0.06";
        textBoxYear.Text = "1";
        textBoxBalance.Text = "0";
        textBoxRemaining.Text = textBoxGoal.Text;
    }

    private void buttonNextYear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Increment the current year.
        _CurrentYear++;

        // Calculate the current balance and remaining diff from goal.
        _CurrentBalance += (Double)Int32.Parse(textBoxYearlyInvest.Text);
        _CurrentBalance += _CurrentBalance * Double.Parse(textBoxInterestRate.Text);
        _CurrentRemaining = (Double)(Int32.Parse(textBoxGoal.Text) - _CurrentBalance);

        // Populate the form elements.
        textBoxYear.Text = _CurrentYear.ToString();
        textBoxBalance.Text = Math.Round(_CurrentBalance, 2).ToString("C");
        textBoxRemaining.Text = Math.Round(_CurrentRemaining, 2).ToString("C");
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I wouldn't advise this code.  Using doubles in a financial application is a pretty big no no.  You should use decimal for financial applications which do not contain floating point errors

Comment: I think that using data binding is a far better option, but otherwise is a nice answer. See mine for a binding-based version of a very similar code.

Comment: @Mick - Yes, you are correct. There are a lot of flaws with my program (in terms of best practices). However, since the OP stated that he was new to C# .NET I didn't want to overwhelm him with too complex of a solution. My solution provides the basics to allow him to better understand how to start with his development efforts.

Comment: There's no added complication with using the correct datatypes.  Just remove all reference to doubles and replace them with decimal.  Using doubles and introducing floating point errors in a financial application can make the difference between the system being complete failure and a success.

Comment: @BillYCode - You need to add event handlers for the button click events that point to the appropriate methods. In my example I had added these event handlers using the designer instead of manually adding them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use data binding for such purposes, as it helps with populating data from your code and reading it back from the user, as well as display formating without too much of a hassle:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public decimal Balance {get; set;}
    public decimal Remaining {get; set;}
    public decimal YearlyGoal {get; set;}
    public decimal YearlyInvest {get; set;}
    public decimal InterestRate {get; set;}

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Year = 0;
        this.Balance = 0;
        this.Remaining = 0;
        this.YearlyGoal = 100000;
        this.YearlyInvest = 2000;
        this.InterestRate = 0.06;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBoxYear.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Year");
        this.textBoxBalance.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Balance", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "c");
        this.textBoxRemaining.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Remaining", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "c");
        this.textBoxYearlyGoal.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "YearlyGoal", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "c");
        this.textBoxYearlyInvest.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "YearlyInvest", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "c");
        this.textBoxInterestRate.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "InterestRate");
    }

    private void buttonNextYear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CurrentYear++;

        this.CurrentBalance += this.YearlyInvest;
        this.CurrentBalance += this,CurrentBalance * this.InterestRate;
        this.CurrentRemaining = this.YearlyGoal - this.CurrentBalance;
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Alejandro , thank you for your answer. Could you please take a look at my edit above? Thank you.

Comment: Good part is that data binding is apparently working, as you're seeing some data and formating. Now, check if you've attached the `Click` event handlers of the buttons to the methods (select the button, F4 to open properties window and look for the events button, then click). You may also set a breakpoint in each handler, both new year and close, and see if it stops when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your textboxes manually in code, then show your remaining from the amount in the goal simply by subtracting the converted value of the string in the box to a float.